# Mysql - Merge two tables by retaining the previous data

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

How can I update `sales` in `products` table depending on `sales` of `productsUPDATE` where `products.id` = `productsUPDATE.id` and while retaining the previous data numbers of `products`?

These are my two tables:

```
# products     # productsUPDATE
id  Sales      id  Sales   
---|-----|     ---|-----|
1  | 10  |     1  | 40  |  
2  | 11  |     2  | 50  | 
3  | 12  |     3  | 80  |
```

I try this query but I lose data sales in `products` table:

```
UPDATE products 
INNER JOIN productsUPDATE ON products.id = productsUPDATE.id 
SET products.sales = productsUPDATE.sales 
WHERE productsUPDATE.id = products.id
```

query ouput:

```
# products     # productsUPDATE
id  Sales      id  Sales   
---|-----|     ---|-----|
1  | 40  |     1  | 40  |  
2  | 50  |     2  | 50  | 
3  | 80  |     3  | 80  |
```

desired output:

```
# products      # productsUPDATE
id    Sales     id  Sales   
---|--------|   ---|-----|
1  | 40,10  |   1  | 40  |  
2  | 50,11  |   2  | 50  | 
3  | 80,12  |   3  | 80  |
```

Comment: i advice you to read [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad) before you continue and get stuck in the future with this bad choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following solution using [`CONCAT_WS`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws):

```
UPDATE products 
INNER JOIN productsUPDATE ON products.id = productsUPDATE.id 
SET products.sales = CONCAT_WS(',', products.sales, productsUPDATE.sales)
WHERE productsUPDATE.id = products.id
```

Instead of storing the data on the `products` table, you can also use a [`VIEW`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-view.html):

```
CREATE VIEW products_current AS
    SELECT p.id, CONCAT_WS(',', GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT p.Sales), GROUP_CONCAT(pu.Sales SEPARATOR ',')) 
    FROM products p INNER JOIN productsUPDATE pu ON p.id = pu.id GROUP BY p.id;
```

> [**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=972839da3354453b936997a0b8b55097)

Answer (score 0):

Seems you want comma separated values

```
UPDATE products 
INNER JOIN productsUPDATE ON products.id = productsUPDATE.id 
SET products.sales = concat(products.sales,',',sproductsUPDATE.sales )
```

but you should avoid the use comma separated  values  you should take a look at normalization  ..